# multiple select with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="example" name="example" multiple="multiple"> <option value="1">Option 1</option> <option value="2">Option 2</option> <option value="3">Option 3</option> <option value="4">Option 4</option> <option value="5">Option 5</option> </select>

<span class="click" id="1">one </span>
<span class="click" id="2">two </span>
<span class="click" id="3">three </span>
<span class="click" id="4">four </span>

$('.click').click( function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#example').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

how can i make that use multiple select and if i click again span with background-color=red then css background-color is again white?

LIVE EXAMPLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/28/

Comment: Sorry but I read your question 4 times and still no idea what you are asking  for.

Comment: the question is unclear .............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that click on multiple items successively results in multiple select options being selected, if this is the case then: [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69naX/) will do the job for you. I switched to using a class as this is (a) better, and (b) easier. If you can't use a class, then it'd be easy enough to tweak.  The main solution however is:

```
$('.click').click( function() {
    var item = $(this);

    if(item.hasClass('Active')) {   
        item.removeClass('Active');
        $('#example > [value="' + this.id + '"]').removeAttr('selected');
    }
    else {
        item.addClass('Active');
        $('#example > [value="' + this.id + '"]').attr('selected', 'true');
    }
});
```

Basically using .val() will select one item, what you need to do is set the "selected" property on the items you want to be selected, allowing multiple ones be selected at once.  if you were using jQuery 1.6 or above, I would advise switching from attr/removeAttr to simply ".prop('selected', true/false); as selected is a DOM property.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all `.click` elements backgrounds to white before you set the current one to red:

```
$('.click').click( function() {
    $('.click').css('background-color', '#FFF');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#example').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: i would like the multiple select, this is for only one selected

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('.click').click( function() {
    if($(this).css('background-color')=='red')
        $(this).css('background-color', 'white');
     if($(this).css('background-color')=='white')
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#example').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.click').click( function() {
    $('.click').css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    $('#example').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: i would like the multiple select, this is for only one selected

Answer (score 0):

You can grab  the select with any of the following selectors: `select`, `select[mutliple=multiple]`, `select#example`.

Personally I'd go with the last one.

Toggling color can be achieved with these small snippet:

```
$('.click').click(function (e) {
  var target = $(this);
  target.css('background-color', ('red' === target.css('background-color') ? 'white' : 'red'));
});
```